# Radio button in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, radio-button

In xamarin form cross platform
My problem is, can I put the radio button to a container then I will set an ID to container so that I will access the radiobtn content via the container's ID. I make an code for this, Idk if its correct sir.
`

```
 <StackLayout RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="ID_type">
                                <RadioButton Content="National ID"/>
                                <RadioButton Content="Voters ID"/>
                                <RadioButton Content="Drivers License"/>
                                <RadioButton Content="PRC ID"/>
                                <RadioButton Content="Postal ID"/>

                                <RadioButton Content="Others:"/>
                            </StackLayout>
```

`

Because it is hassle to put ID in each content of radiobutton.
any link or article that will be commented, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the parent is `StackLayout`, you can traverse its children by referring to property `x:Name` of `StackLayout`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
   <StackLayout RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="fruits" x:Name="mStackLayout"> 
        <!-- All of the RadioButtons in this StackLayout will automatically be given the
             GroupName 'fruits' -->
        <RadioButton Content="Apple" />
        <RadioButton Content="Banana" />
        <RadioButton Content="Pineapple" />
        <RadioButton Content="Other" />
    </StackLayout>

    <Button  Text="test" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```

Function `Button_Clicked`:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {

        var children = mStackLayout.Children;

        foreach (var child in children) {

            if (child is RadioButton) {

                RadioButton button = (RadioButton) child;

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" one child 's content is : " + button.Content);
            
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help.  I really appreciate it. I have some clarification to your code sir, if I will insert to database,  I just need to make some little changes in the code right? ( sorry for my english hehe)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. What does the question you ask above have to do with database? Can you explain your problem in detail?

Comment: it goes like this sir,I have a page( create account ) so user must take input like firstname,lastname,contact number, and one of the input field is to make sure the customer is legit or not, so the customer need to upload a valid ID picture, so I make an radiobutton just like I posted. ++

Comment: so it should be like this – (e.g dummy data)
 name: juan 
 lastname: rain
ID type: postal ID
image: img.jpg

Comment: thats why I ask sir how to make that radiobutton in group because my first code is basically like this
 <RadioButton Content="National ID"/>
                                <RadioButton Content="Voters ID"/>
                                <RadioButton Content="Drivers License"/>
                                <RadioButton Content="PRC ID"/>
                                <RadioButton Content="Postal ID"/>
and after customer will chose in the radiobutton,I will insert it to database

Comment: I should have understood, you are trying to insert Radio's content into the database, right?

Comment: yes sir,that why I ask how to make the radio in group and how to access its content then insert to db, but dont worry your code posted is highly appreciated, I have some little clarification in my first reply in your comment.

Comment: Ok, in the code I posted, you can also get the `IsChecked` status for all  `RadioButton`s  status by code:   `RadioButton button = (RadioButton) child;
  bool status = button.IsChecked;
`